# How i can auto add _locale to url in annotations

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations

Hi i got my route to "front" controller,

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/{furl}", defaults={"_locale"="pl","furl"=" "}, name="front", requirements={"_locale"="pl|de|en"})
 * @Route("/{furl}", defaults={"_locale"="pl"})
 */
```

And now it is the problem, becouse when we got, i.e. url /pl/test it works as /test aswell, but how to make some rewrite if someone write /test it will be /pl/test in as defaults locale, becouse it is important for seo to got one specify link. Its cool that works both, but how to auto rewrite /test to /pl/test it is possible in annotation ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to redirect your root url `'/'` to `'/pl'` and only enable `'/pl/test'`?

Here is a way to do so in `config/routes/annotations.yaml`

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: 
      pl: '/pl'
      de: '/de'
      en: '/en'

root:
    path: '/'
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: '/pl'
        permanent: true
```

See more at [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html)